# Flutter - Reactive BLE lib - random disconnects of connected devices

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a BLE reactive Flutter library to communicate between STM32WB and my Android phone app (Android 12). Multiple devices (STMs) can be connected to the app at the same time. If one of the devices timeouts, it goes over my disconnection procedure. That works well, but every now and then there is a bug, that some other STM also disconnects without even going over my disconnect functions. What could be the cause of that?

Library github:
https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble#readme

Test case
In this test 3 STM devices were connected to the phone. I purposely timeouted 00:80:E1:26:D2:6D. After that 00:80:E1:26:E6:CC also disconnected itself, but not over my functions. The third device stayed connected and working as it should.

```
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): onPhyUpdate() - status=0 address=00:80:E1:26:D2:6D txPhy=2 rxPhy=2
// *** I turn off the power to one STM so it timeouts for testing (status 8 - Connection timeout)
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=9 device=00:80:E1:26:D2:6D
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000aa02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): close()
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): unregisterApp() - mClientIf=9
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ac02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ad02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ae02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
// *** My disconnection handling functions get called.
[log] Connecting widget: bt disconnected
[log] Battery provider: removed battery 00:80:E1:26:D2:6D
[log] Handling connection lost from: 00:80:E1:26:D2:6D
[log] Disconnecting device: 00:80:E1:26:D2:6D
// *** Procedure to disconnect the timeouted device completed.
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ad03-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000af02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ad04-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
// *** All 7 streams of disconnected STM get canceled ok
// *** Randomly another device disconnects, but not over my disconnect procedure.
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): cancelOpen() - device: 00:80:E1:26:E6:CC
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=11 device=00:80:E1:26:E6:CC
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000aa02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ac02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ad02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ae02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ad03-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000af02-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ad04-8e22-4541-9d4c-21edae82ed19 enable: false
// *** All its 7 streams get canceled.
D/BluetoothGatt(27591): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=11 device=00:80:E1:26:E6:CC
// *** My third STM is still connected and working ok tho
```

Main BLE Reactive function that handles connection changes:

```
  Future<void> handleBluetoothConnectionChanges(String deviceUuid) async {
    QueuedDevices device = connectedDevices.where((element) => element.device.id == deviceUuid).first;
    device.subscription = Provider.of<BleDeviceConnector>(context, listen: false).state.listen((event) async {
      switch(event.connectionState){

        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnected:
          if(device.connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.disconnected || device.device.id != event.deviceId)
            return;

          Globals.gLogMessage("Connecting widget: bt disconnected", MessageType.DEBUG);
          
          // Handles all UI changes etc. Nothing directly related to BLE connection.
          await Provider.of<BatteriesModel>(context, listen: false).removeBattery(context, deviceUuid);

          // Cancels connection and removes device
          await handleConnectionLostOrTimeout(device);
          break;
      }
      device.connectionState = event.connectionState;
    })..onError((error){
      Globals.gLogMessage("EXCEPTION - device connection error!: " + error.toString(), MessageType.ERROR_FATAL);
    });
  }
```

handleConnectionLostOrTimeout()

```
  Future<void> handleConnectionLostOrTimeout(QueuedDevices device) async {
    try {
      Globals.gLogMessage("Handling connection lost from: " + device.device.id, MessageType.DEBUG);
      await device.subscription?.cancel();
      await Provider.of<BleDeviceConnector>(context, listen: false).disconnect(device.device.id);
      connectedDevices.removeWhere((element) => element.device.id == device.device.id);
    }
    catch(exception) {
      Globals.gLogMessage(exception.toString(), MessageType.ERROR_FATAL);
    }
  }
```